# Unset pm3d map in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I know I can make a color map of a splot with

```
set pm3d map
```

but how can I unset this option?

```
unset pm3d map
```

gives an error and

```
unset pm3d
unset map
```

both result in an splot with a fixed "top-down" view, making it impossible to see anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should unset the view variable, use

```
unset view
```

also would be useful to

```
unset pm3d
```

should be back again to normal if you are using GNU Plot 4.x :)

Comment: Thanks! This has been driving me nuts for a while.